# KeyError: 0 Plotting Labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm a bit new to matplotlib. I am trying to plot labels for each (x,y) coordinate in my line graph. I am getting a Keyerror: 0 for this line of code: x = df[i]['DATE_DATE']

When I run print(df['DATE_DATE']), I get the following values:

```
0     Sep 29
1     Sep 30
2     Oct 01
3     Oct 02
4     Oct 03
5     Oct 04
6     Oct 05
7     Oct 06
8     Oct 07
9     Oct 08
10    Oct 09
11    Oct 10
12    Oct 11
13    Oct 12
```

Here is the entire code for context:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from connect_to_db import get_df2

df = get_df2()
df['DATE_DATE'] = df['DATE_DATE'].dt.strftime('%b %d')

ax = df.plot(x='DATE_DATE', y='Sum', fontsize=10, color='#5C7AA6', linewidth=2.0, legend=False,
             xlabel='', ylabel='Sum', figsize=(10, 5)).grid(axis='y')

for i in range(len(df)):
    x = df[i]['DATE_DATE']
    y = df[i]['Sum']
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    plt.text(x * (1 + 0.01), y * (1 + 0.01), i, fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting a Keyerror in this for loop when there appears to be objects in that column?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: looks like you have your indexing backwards - try printing `x[0]["DATE_DONE"]`, it should give a key error. Now try printing `x["DATE_DONE"][0]`

Comment: Well that's really awkward. Thanks for the help!

Comment: happens to the best of us!